# How to communicate(=upload) with SSL-protected server with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, zerossl

## Background

I build up a SSL-protected server on AWS(EC2). I installed Python v3.10.10 and confirmed that ssl module can be imported successfully. I registered my domain name on ZeroSSL and my domain is shown to be successfully issued. I use nginx as a server software. Downloading some file from this server is successful but uploading a file can not be available. So I posted this question.

## Environment

- AWS EC2
- Rloging(v2.27.7) for Windows
- Python(v3.10.10) on EC2
- nginx(1.22.1) on EC2
- Windows11 64bit (local computer)
- [pyuac]1

## Crt files and its private.key

I downloaded a zipfile from my dashboard page on ZeroSSL. When I unzip it, there are 3 files: certificate.crt, ca_bundle.crt and private.key. In the [document][2] which describes **SSLContext.load_cert_chain** function, it says,

> Load a private key and the corresponding certificate. The certfile string must be the path to a single file in PEM format containing the certificate as well as any number of CA certificates needed to establish the certificate’s authenticity. The keyfile string, if present, must point to a file containing the private key.

So I converted each crt files into pem-format by typing as follows on local computer:

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -out certificate.pem -outform pem
openssl x509 -in ca_bundle.crt -out ca_bundle.pem -outform pem
```

Then I copied 2 pem files and private key to 'c:\Program Files\common files\SSL' on my local computer.

## Configuration

Configuration of nginx is as follows:

```
http{
    server{
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate "/etc/ssl/certificate.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/ssl/private.key";
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-HSA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-HSA384;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        server_name my_domain.org

        location / {
            root /path_to_the_document;
            index index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

## Python script #1

As a test, I made a scipt to upload 'test.py' on local computer to 'my_domain.org/hoge' on EC2.

```
import urllib.request
import ssl

header = {"Content-Type": "text/csv"}
with open("test.py", mode="rb") as fb:
    content = fb.read()

context = ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="c:\\users\\myname\\downloads\\my_domain.org",
                        keyfile="c:\\users\\myname\\downloads\\my_domain.org\\private.key")
req = urllib.request.Request(url="my_domain.org/hoge",
                             data=content,
                             headers=header,
                             method='POST')

with urllib.request.urlopen(req, context=context) as res:
    print(res.read())
```

## Error #1

When I ran the script, following error was obtained.

```
File "hogehoge/scratch.py", line 9, in <module>
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile="c:\\users\\myname\\downloads\\my_domain.org",
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

## Python Script #2 from the Error #1

I thought UAC control on Windows11 hinders my script running. So I serached around and found the package 'pyuac' and then I embedded my script as follows:

```
import urllib.request
import ssl
import pyuac

def main():
    header = {"Content-Type": "text/csv"}
    with open("test.py", mode="rb") as fb:
        content = fb.read()

    context = ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile="c:\\users\\myname\\downloads\\my_domain.org",
                            keyfile="c:\\users\\myname\\downloads\\my_domain.org\\private.key")
    req = urllib.request.Request(url="my_domain.org/hoge",
                                 data=content,
                                 headers=header,
                                 method='POST')

    with urllib.request.urlopen(req, context=context) as res:
        print(res.read())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not pyuac.isUserAdmin():
        pyuac.runAsAdmin()
    else:
        main()
```

## Result and my question

When I ran the script, UAC window popup appears and the script ends in exit(0). So 'permission denied error' at Error #1 came up because my script did not run as an administrator priviledge. Here there is no error while running this script but 'test.py' was not uploaded. Please tell me what I should do next ?

Thanks for reading my question. I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: load_cert_chain with certfile and keyfile  in the client are only needed for mTLS (mutual authentication, i.e. client certificates). Your server does not require this, so remove it.